# Reading ini file in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am trying to read an ini file that has the following format:

```
SETTING=VALUE 
SETTING2=VALUE2
```

I currently have the following code:

```
string cache = sr.ReadToEnd();                    
string[] splitCache = cache.Split(new string[] {"\n", "\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Which gives me a list of settings, however, what I would like to do is read this into a dictionary.  My question is, is there a way to do this without iterating through the entire array and manually populating the dictionary?

Comment: why not just use a foreach loop?

Comment: I could - but the question was could I do it without itterating through the array.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/readwritexmlini.aspx is a good INI reader if you want to skip the donkey work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you could use LINQ and do

```
Dictionary<string, string> ini = (from entry in splitCache
                                  let key = entry.Substring(0, entry.FirstIndexOf("="))
                                  let value = entry.Substring(entry.FirstIndexOf("="))
                                  select new { key, value }).ToDictionary(e => e.key, e => e.value);
```

As Binary Worrier points out in the comments, this way of doing this has no advantages over the simple loop suggested by the other answers.

**Edit:** A shorter version of the block above would be

```
Dictionary<string, string> ini = splitCache.ToDictionary(
                                   entry => entry.Substring(0, entry.FirstIndexOf("="),
                                   entry => entry.Substring(entry.FirstIndexOf("="));
```

Comment: @pm_2. be aware that this simply hiding a very simple loop under some fairly ugly linq. +1 for answering the question as asked, however I'd rather the loop.

Comment: Other than the obvious readability issue, are there any other down-sides to using this method?

Comment: @pm_2: You cannot step through LINQ expressions using the debugger. Other than that, I don't know any.

Comment: There's an upside. The compiler/runtime is more likely to be able to automatically parellize LINQ written code so that it can be ran on multiple CPUs than it can a loop.

Answer (score 7):

What is wrong with iterating?

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("pathtoyourfile.ini");
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach(var s in lines)
{
     var split = s.Split("=");
     dict.Add(split[0], split[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's actually a Windows API for reading/writing INI files in `kernel32.dll`; see [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/aejw_ini_class.aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

INI files are a bit tricky so I wouldn't recommend rolling your own.  I wrote [Nini](http://nini.sourceforge.net/) which is a configuration library that [includes](http://nini.sourceforge.net/Reference/html/Nini.Ini.IniDocument.html) a very fast parser.

Sample INI file:

```
; This is a comment
[My Section]
key 1 = value 1
key 2 = value 2

[Pets]
dog = rover
cat = muffy
```

Same C# code:

```
// Load the file
IniDocument doc = new IniDocument ("test.ini");

// Print the data from the keys
Console.WriteLine ("Key 1: " + doc.Get ("My Section", "key 1"));
Console.WriteLine ("Key 2: " + doc.Get ("Pets", "dog"));

// Create a new section
doc.SetSection ("Movies");

// Set new values in the section
doc.SetKey ("Movies", "horror", "Scream");
doc.SetKey ("Movies", "comedy", "Dumb and Dumber");

// Remove a section or values from a section
doc.RemoveSection ("My Section");
doc.RemoveKey ("Pets", "dog");

// Save the changes
doc.Save("test.ini");
```

Comment: Nice and certainly useful for all the non-trivial uses of ini files.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetPrivateProfileString")]

public static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string SectionName, string KeyName, string Default, StringBuilder Return_StringBuilder_Name, int Size, string FileName);
```

and call the function like this

```
GetPrivateProfileString(Section_Name, "SETTING", "0", StringBuilder_Name, 10, "filename.ini");
```

Value can be accessed from `StringBuilder_Name`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not read the file as separate lines, then loop over them splitting on the first `=`?

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filename)) {
  var parts = line.Split('=', 2); // Maximum of 2 parts, so '=' in value ignored.
  dict.Add(parts[0], parts[1]);
}
```

(In .NET 4 replace `ReadAllLines` with `ReadLines`, to avoid creating the array, `ReadLines` returns `IEnumerable<String>` and reads the file lazily.)

Comment: should be `dict.Add(parts[0], parts[1]);`, shouldn't it?