# C#: Storing the content of an ini file as string or dictionary instead of file name?

Tags: c#, forms, dictionary, ini

Is there a way to store the content of a file as string or as a dictionary instead of just its file path/name?

Below is the method that I am currently using for getting the file path from a Windows Form. Is there a way to adapt it or should I start from scratch? I am loading .ini files which is only text. [LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817578/reading-ini-file-in-c-sharp) seems to be one route but I am not familiar with it.

```
public void ShowSettingsGui()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog ofd = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Multiselect = false;
    ofd.Filter = "Data Sources (*.ini)|*.ini*|All Files|*.*";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string[] filePath = ofd.FileNames;
    }
    m_settings = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you read the file into an array with the (of gosh!) `System.IO.Filexxx` classes.

Comment: your code allows multiselect. Do you want to store the content of all selected files?

Comment: `I saw someone using LINQ for it but I don't understand it.` And I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @L.B please can you tell me which part you don't understand for me to clarify and make the question better?

Comment: LINQ is irrelevant here. What you need is basics of the File operations. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx for a simple tutorial. Once you are able to **read** the file, you can put the data to a list or dictionary, whatever you like.

Comment: @codesparkle I only want to store the content of one file.

Comment: then **why** do you have multiselect enabled? which file would you like to store? Anyway, it should be easy to adapt for one file ;)

Comment: @codesparkle I didn't think this would cause an issue. I will make it false, thank you. I am trying to store a settings file and later on extract some lines from it.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl thank you I will look into string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines;

Comment: @arthurmani you have the filename with `ofd.FileName`, I don't realy understand why you don't use `File.ReadAllBytes` , `File.ReadAllText` , `File.WriteAllBytes` or `File.WriteAllText`

Comment: @ColeJohnson when using `string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines;` I get an error saying:Cannot convert method group 'ReadAllLines' to non-delegate type 'string[]'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: you need to add parentheses to the method name. `string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines();`. This is exactly why I told codesparkle that showing you the LINQ'ed version will introduce further confusion. In some LINQ-lines, you are allowed to "pass a function to the LINQ", where I mean: Give-LINQ-A-Function. In those cases, you do it like with a variable, so you just write `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines`. Now however, you wanted to run the function instantly, not to give it to someone to play with it. You wanted to Call-A-Function, and you do it with parens: `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()`.

Comment: And there's one more thing: the `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` takes a **parameter**, because the function has to be told **what file** you want to read. If you write just a `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` it will be an error, because it will not know what to read. Thus, a filename must be passed: `string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\\blah\\boom.ini");` and now it will be OK. Of course, the filename doesn't have to be hardcoded, it can be sitting in a variable, or can be got from fileDialog.FileName directly: `string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dialog.FileName);`

Comment: Here comes the LINQ confusion for 'newbies': Note that the LINQ said `paths.ToDictionary(filePath => filePath, File.ReadAllText)` so no parameters for ReadAllText, while the 'handmade-code` said `.. = File.ReadAllText(filename);` otherwise it was an error. Thanks to a few smart mechamisms, LINQ is able to gues and insert the parameters for you - but only if you craft the rest of the line very carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ is indeed a nice way to do it: We simply convert the paths to a dictionary (where they become the keys). The values are determined by calling [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) on every file path.

```
var dialog = new OpenFileDialog() { Multiselect = true, 
    Filter = "Data Sources (*.ini)|*.ini*|All Files|*.*" };
if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
var paths = dialog.FileNames;
var fileContents = paths.ToDictionary(filePath => filePath, File.ReadAllText);
```

To help you understand what's going one here, take a look at the (roughly equivalent) non-LINQ version. Here, we explicitly iterate over the FileNames and add them as keys to our dictionary while again calling `File.ReadAllText` on every one of them.

```
// same as first snippet without the last line
foreach (var filePath in paths)
{
    fileContents.Add(filePath, File.ReadAllText(filePath));
}
```

Set a breakpoint to the last line of each snippet, run them and take a look at the contents of the dictionary to determine the result.

EDIT: It wasn't clear in the question, but it seems you're only interested in a single file name. That means you don't need LINQ at all (`m_settings` needs to be a `string`).

```
var dialog = new OpenFileDialog{Filter = "Data Sources (*.ini)|*.ini*|All Files|*.*"};
if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
m_settings = File.ReadAllText(dialog.FileName);
```

Comment: +!, because your answer is 100% valid and correct. However, I believe that it will not help the question author to understand the file operations..

Comment: @quetzalcoatl that's true, the `File` class is a very high-level wrapper but I think it just doesn't make sense to use StreamReaders and the like for File access anymore...

Comment: @codesparkle thank you very much, sorry why is the File class a high-level wrapper?

Comment: @arthurmani by that, I mean that it *hides* the details of file access from you - which is convenient because the resulting code is nice and clear. There is [an example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx) showing the old, more error-prone way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks lot @codesparkle do you know why I get the following output instead of the dictionary in itself?             {0}
0. System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]

Answer (score 0):

if you can add description of what are you trying to accomplish it would help.

just the same, I would use to store/read settings by using the settings class

here is a link to how to use it:
 [write user settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755.aspx)

I used in the past xml to parse a settings file, i find it much easier than reading ini in a sequential manner.

Hope it helps

Comment: never mind, i see that you are looking for file names and paths