# Using a LINQ variable in another method?

Tags: c#, linq, grasshopper

In the code below, I am trying to assign the array `Filepaths` to the variable `m_settings` but `Filepaths` is not recognized outside the LINQ method. How can I store the content of `FilePaths` in a variable that i can use in the `SolveInstance` method?

```
public void ShowSettingsGui()
{
    var dialog = new OpenFileDialog()
    {
        Multiselect = true,
        Filter = "Data Sources (*.ini)|*.ini*|All Files|*.*"
    };
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
    var paths = dialog.FileNames;
    var FilePaths = paths.ToDictionary(filePath => filePath, File.ReadAllText);
}

private string[] m_settings = Filepaths;  

protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
{
    if (m_settings == null)
    {
        AddRuntimeMessage(GH_RuntimeMessageLevel.Warning, "You must declare some valid settings");
        return;
    }

    DA.SetData(0, m_settings);
}
```

Comment: Can you not just assign m_settings in the ShowSettingsGui method and use m_settings in SolveInstance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be reading into it too much but I don't think you need FilePaths, you can just set m_settings directly...

```
private Dictionary<string, string> m_settings;  

public void ShowSettingsGui()
{
    var dialog = new OpenFileDialog()
    {
        Multiselect = true,
        Filter = "Data Sources (*.ini)|*.ini*|All Files|*.*"
    };
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
    var paths = dialog.FileNames;
    m_settings = paths.ToDictionary(filePath => filePath, File.ReadAllText);
}

protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
{
    if (m_settings == null)
    {
        AddRuntimeMessage(GH_RuntimeMessageLevel.Warning, "You must declare some valid settings");
        return;
    }

    DA.SetData(0, m_settings);
}
```

You also need to ensure SolveInstance is called after ShowSettingsGui, otherwise m_settings will always be null

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you know why I get the following output and not the dictionnary in itself? '{0}
0. System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'

Comment: @arthurmani, you are only after a single file. Don't use a dictionary. just do `string m_settings;` and `m_settings = File.ReadAllText(dialog.FileName);`. The output is like that because that's what `Dictionary.ToString` returns.

Comment: @arthurmani I've updated my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11926808/1106367) to show you how.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ShowSettingsGui()
{
    var dialog = new OpenFileDialog()
    {
        Multiselect = true,
        Filter = "Data Sources (*.ini)|*.ini*|All Files|*.*"
    };
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
    var paths = dialog.FileNames;
    var FilePaths = paths.ToDictionary(filePath => filePath, File.ReadAllText);

    // You need to add this
    this.m_settings  = FilePaths;
}

// You also need to change the type of m_settings from string[] to Dictionary<string, string>
private Dictionary<string, string> m_settings = Filepaths;  

protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
{
    if (m_settings == null)
    {
        AddRuntimeMessage(GH_RuntimeMessageLevel.Warning, "You must declare some valid settings");
        return;
    }

    DA.SetData(0, m_settings);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I get the following `error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>' to 'string[]'` and `The name 'Filepaths' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: You've got a floating member declared in between the methods. Firstly, move that to the top. Once you do that, you'll realise that Filepaths doesn't exist at that level and so assigning m_settings to Filepaths is invalid.